# Can't place correct order of significant values over my bar graph (emmeans_test rearranges factors)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm doing a one way ANOVA using `rstatix` and want to put significant pairwise test values (using `emmeans_test`) over my plot.

However, the output from `emmeans_test` reorders my factors. So the significance values are not correctly placed on the right bars.

Here is example data:

```
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)

#dataframe
ER <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  Sex  Group ER
  M    V     1046
  M    V     1290
  M    Z     1202
  M    Z     1056
  F    V     8000
  F    V     7859
  F    Z     4000
  F    Z     3409
")

ER <- ER %>%
  set_ref_level("Sex", ref = "M") #set males as my reference
```

`ER$Sex` shows my factors in the correct order, males first

However, after I do `emmeans_test`, the output changes. Maybe in alphabetical order?

```
res.aov <- ER %>% anova_test(ER ~ Sex * Group)
res.aov

pwc <- ER %>% 
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  emmeans_test(ER ~ Group, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni") #output now has females first. 

pwc
```

I tried to specify the order, in the way I want it to be in the plot, males first, then females, last females + T. Doing this does not change anything.

```
pwc1 <- pwc[c(2,1),]
pwc1

#plot data 
e <- ggboxplot(ER, x = "Sex", y = "ER", color = "Group",
               palette = "jco")
print(e)

pwc1 <- pwc1 %>% add_xy_position(x = "Sex")

e + stat_pvalue_manual(pwc1) + labs(subtitle = get_test_label(res.aov, detailed = TRUE),
    caption = get_pwc_label(pwc1))
```

My plot is in the correct order (Males, Females) but the significance values are switched.
Please let me know what I'm missing! I've been looking for a fix online for days and trying different things to no avail.

(Thank you in advance, also I'm an R noob, so I apologize if I made a mistake in the code/post above)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You added a snippet of you data, which is very good. However, to make your question reproducible and to help us to help you, you should add the code you used to make `res.aov` and `pwc1`. Otherwise it's hard to figure out a solution as we can't run your code. See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will make those changes now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the `rstatix` and the `ggpubr` package. However, as you alreday figured out by your self, after doing the `emmeans_test` the order of your `Sex` variable gets lost, i.e. it gets converted to a character and hence you get the alphabetical order. A solution to this issue is to convert `Sex` in your `pwc` data back to a factor and set the levels as in your `ER` dataset using `factor(Sex, levels = levels(ER$Sex))`:

```r
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)

#dataframe
ER <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  Sex  Group ER
  M    V     1046
  M    V     1290
  M    Z     1202
  M    Z     1056
  F    V     8000
  F    V     7859
  F    Z     4000
  F    Z     3409
")

ER <- ER %>%
  mutate(Sex = factor(Sex)) %>% 
  set_ref_level("Sex", ref = "M") #set males as my reference

res.aov <- ER %>% 
  anova_test(ER ~ Sex * Group)
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()

pwc <- ER %>% 
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  emmeans_test(ER ~ Group, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni") %>% #output now has females first.
  # Set levels of Sex as in your ER dataset
  mutate(Sex = factor(Sex, levels = levels(ER$Sex)))

pwc1 <- pwc[c(2,1),]

#plot data 
e <- ggboxplot(ER, x = "Sex", y = "ER", color = "Group",
               palette = "jco")

pwc1 <- pwc1 %>% add_xy_position(x = "Sex")

e + stat_pvalue_manual(pwc1) + 
  labs(subtitle = get_test_label(res.aov, detailed = TRUE),
       caption = get_pwc_label(pwc1))
```

[image]

Comment: Have you done the conversion inside `mutate`, i.e. `mutate(Sex = factor(Sex, levels = levels(ER$Sex)))` as in my code? Otherwise it will throw you this error message.

Comment: Just tried it in my larger data set, and it worked perfectly! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I see you saw my first message. Yes I edited it, because I realized what I did wrong. Accidentally separated the code.